# Summing and then append the values of a column using awk command

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying, **to append**, the summing result of my file's marks, **after summing them**.

---

My file is locate in, **/home/evaluation**, and contains this :

- English 16
- History 14
- Biology 15

---

**I would like to have something like this** :

- English 16
- History 14
- Biology 15
- **Total : 45**

---

** So far, I went to this :

```
for file in /home/evaluation/* ; do
    awk '{sum+=$2} END {print "total:" sum}' "$file"
done
```

Unfortunately it only prints the summing values, but does not append it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you not able to make your `awk` command something like this and just do an `>>` append?

```sh
awk '{sum+=$2} END {print "total:" sum}' "$file" >> $file
```

You could make it slightly more elegant - e.g. add an if condition to only add the line `total:` if the line does not exist already.

Comment: Oh my God true...

I completely forgot ">>" was for append..

Thank you very much for reminding me that mate

Comment: No worries. Sometimes I can get so far down the rabbit hole I forget the most basic stuff - I do it on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk:

```
$ awk '{t+=$2}ENDFILE{print "Total",t >> FILENAME}' file
$ cat file
English 16
History 14
Biology 15
Total 45
```

After `strace`ing that some I think there should be a `close(FILENAME)` in the end of the `ENDFILE` if you use it for multiple files.

Comment: Thank you very much ! My fault I forgot ">>" was for append.